# How to know the variable and class associated with a dialog in visual c++ 2008?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, modal-dialog

Can any one please help me to know the class and variable associated with a mfc dialog in visual c++ 2008. Also how to dis-associate the class and delete it.

And same for a control variable too.

With Regards,
Safee

Comment: The answers are in your code. If you don't know where, get a copy of Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0072850574) (absolutely, positively mandatory reading, if you are having difficulty telling the IDE and the library apart.).

Answer (score 0):

What's the the title you see in the form's title bar? Then go to your .rc file, there must be a line with

```
CAPTION "Title"
```

and above it a line like

```
`IDD_YOUR_FORM_ID DIALOGEX left, right, width, height`
```

where the parameters are self describing numbers. Then search for `IDD_YOUR_FORM_ID`on the entire solution and you will be guided to the `.cpp` or header file you are looking for.

Comment: I got the answer in the thread, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131394/how-does-visual-studio-associate-mfc-dialog-classes-with-dialog-resources?rq=1

Still thanks for your effort and help.